# Google Maps API v3 is returning the wrong location (coordinates)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Map GeoCoder v3 (JSON) to get the coordinates for

```
Praia do forte
Mata de São João, Bahia 
Brazil
```

The Google Geocoder API *can't* find it, but http://maps.google.com *can* find it.

Google Maps Site
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Praia+do+forte,+Mata+de+S%C3%A3o+Jo%C3%A3o,+Bahia,+Brazil&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&authuser=0

This is the Google Maps API v3 **request** URL I'm hitting to geocode

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Praia%2Bdo%2Bforte%252C%2BMata%2Bde%2BS%25C3%25A3o%2BJo%25C3%25A3o%252C%2BBahia%2B%252C%2BBrazil

This is the **response**.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Praia",
               "short_name" : "Praia",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Praia",
               "short_name" : "Praia",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Cape Verde",
               "short_name" : "CV",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Praia, Cape Verde",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 14.97272960,
                  "lng" : -23.47061630
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 14.90016530,
                  "lng" : -23.54284290
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 14.9304640,
               "lng" : -23.5126690
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 14.95202550,
                  "lng" : -23.48065420
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 14.90890030,
                  "lng" : -23.54468380
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

It's obviously tripping up on the word "Praia" which is a city in Cape Verde.

Comment: Do you have the choice to enter postal code?

Comment: In the web app, yes there is the possibility to enter a zip code, but I don't think a zip code exists for this location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API geocoder is different from the Maps geocoder (see the FAQ in the API documentation).

However, providing *just* enough information to identify the place works:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Praia+do+forte,Brazil

Comment: that's interesting that providing less information would actually result in a more accurate location.